# How to know if database is updated or not using java program

Tags: java, mysql, api

I have two modules. For those two modules database is the common point

- Module 1: Collects the information and store in database
- Module 2: using database results perform the further action

But here there is no connection between Module 1 & Module 2. Now my question is how the second module will trigger automatically when database values are updated?
Is there any method to know database is updated or not?

Comment: include a flag when inserting data. after processing that data, you alter the flag so you know that that entry has been processed

Comment: Why are you designing it in this way?  Why can't you create a connection between Module 1 and Module 2 to say that data is available?

Comment: @JoeC `Module1` will further run in different machines and collect the data and store data in database server. so `Module2` will invoke when the database is updated

Comment: Make this an event based system and broadcast the update using observer/observable pattern.

Comment: @ XtremeBaumer  how to include a flag

Comment: @ThinkSmart What you are talking about here sounds very similar to microservices.

You should have Module3 for sending messages between modules, or at the very least a shared component that allows the two modules to notify each other of an event.
In the same way threading works, you need to pass messages round.

Or you can poll the database for a flag on each row that increments for each update but that seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have tree options:

1. Create a procedure in database listening when there is new updates
2. Store in your Module A a flag with the last updated field and check every `t` seconds if has any updated row
3. Create a messaging interface between the two services.

My comments:

1. Avoid that solution. It is a BAD SOLUTION! It is difficult to track with the code.
2. It can be a good solution if you know that your system will not grow.
3. If you see in the future more modules that can communicate with each other. Do that! Choose a good Message Queue (RabbitMQ, ActiveMC, etc...) or use you cloud solution (AWS has SQS)

---

Communication between two independent modules using database is not a good solution. Because if you change the database schema you will need to make two deploys. If you only need the data, you can use a Message solution using Protobuf as serializer.